# Using a decorator inside an Angular input decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I use an Angular Input property as a parameter for a custom decorator?

some-component.html

```
<some-component [key]="'someString'"></some-component>
```

some.component.ts

```
export class SomeComponent {
  @Input()
  set key(value: string) {
    @SomeCustomDecorator(value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want for example a `log decorator` for all your input setters you can use the following `decorator/function`:

```
function Log(): any {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string | symbol, propertyDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const key = Symbol();
    return {
      get() {
        return this[key]; 
      },
      set(newValue: any) {
        console.log('decorator: ', newValue);
        this[key] = newValue;
        if (propertyDescriptor) {
          propertyDescriptor.set(newValue);
        }
        return this;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It can be used as the following:

```
@Input() @Log() foo;
@Input() @Log() set bar(v) {
  console.log('set bar: ', v);
}
```

The decorator will emit the following logs if you use the `@Input() foo` or `@Input() bar`:

**decorator: "value"**

Running [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-decorator-logger-get-set?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: It's not really what i'm looknig for. The value of the Key input property (someString) should be a parameter for the decorator

Comment: In this example the value of the key input (someString) is available inside the decorator. The value is provided inside the decorator as newValue. Try to check the stackblitz. If you want to give your Decorator an custom param then declare the param in the first line. "function Log(param: any)"